# Обработка POST запроса без подгрузки скрипта

Tags: php, post

Не знаю, точно ли я сформулировал вопрос или нет, если что подправьте.

У меня есть модальное окно с формой, которая отправляет post запрос в обработчик script.php

```
        <form class="em" action="script.php">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <button class="button7" name="sendbtn" >Оформить подписку</button>
        </form>
```

Соответственно после отправки формы пользователя кидает на script.php.
Можно ли как то выполнить этот скрипт не переходя в файл, может прям в этом файле можно обработать? и после обработки поменять содержимое дива соответственно. (да, можно сделать редирект в script.php, но это не совсем то что мне нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обработчик события формы `submit` для отправки ajax запроса. (Не забудьте добавить в страницу скрипт библиотеки jQuery, если его там еще нет.)

```
$('form.em').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'script.php',
    dataType:'html',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success:function(response){
      $('#your div id').html(response);
    },
    error:function(response){
      alert('error, response - ' + response);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, нужно отправлять ajax запрос с помощью js и после ответа изменять html js методами.

И еще похоже вы забыли указать метод

```
<form class="em" action="script.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: да, опечатался просто